# Error message "Empty entity body" returned after making LinkedIn API call

Tags: node.js, http, entity

I'm trying to use the [LinkedIn API to create a post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/share-on-linkedin) using Node & Express with the [node-fetch package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) to make the requests, however I always seem to get the error message "Empty entity body is not allowed for create method request" and I don't know how to resolve the error. I've included the body in the request but I guess not in the correct way. I also get the error code 400 so I know I'm doing something wrong, I'm just not sure what.

My questions are:

- What is the entity body?
- And how do I add it to my request?

```
function newPost(req, done) {
    const id = "XXX";
    const url = "https://api.linkedin.com/v2/ugcPosts";
    const title = "Title title";
    const text = "Text text";
    const body = {
        owner: `urn:li:person:${id}`,
        subject: title,
        text: {
            text: text,
        },
        content: {
            title: title,
        },
    };
    const headers = {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${YYY}`,
        'cache-control': 'no-cache',
        'X-Restli-Protocol-Version': '2.0.0',
        'x-li-format': 'json',
    }
    fetch(url, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: headers,
        json: body,
    }).then(res => res.json()).then(result => {
        console.log(result);
        const message = {
            text: "Posted",
            success: true,
        }
        done(message, "linkedin");
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        const message = {
            text: "Failed",
            success: false,
        }
        done(message, "linkedin");
    });
}
```

Comment: According to a given link to the API URL should be `https://api.linkedin.com/v2/ugcPosts` instead of `https://api.linkedin.com/v2/shares`

Comment: removing linkedin tags since this seems to be an issue with how you're using fetch, not with your use of LinkedIn API.

Answer (score 0):

As described in the to the doc, [Post with JSON](https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch#post-with-json) section, you should `JSON.stringify` the json body object, so try this:

```
fetch(url, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: headers,
        json: JSON.stringify(body),
```

instead of:

```
fetch(url, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: headers,
        json: body,
```

Answer (score 0):

While calling fetch, you aren't passing `body` anywhere, you're passing `json` instead, which seems like a typo.

Existing code:

```
fetch(url, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: headers,
    json: body,
}
```

What it should be instead:

```
fetch(url, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: headers,
    body: JSON.stringify(body),
}
```